# Synchronous AJAX call not truly synchronous

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm having trouble with a synchronous AJAX request.

I am creating a web application where there are many AJAX requests called in sequence which should be returned in strict order. Rather than putting every succeeding request in the readystatechange event handler of the last request, I decided to simply call them synchronously.

However, in the following code, alert() is invoked *before* adding the response to the DOM.

```
window.addEventListener("load", main, false);

function main (e) {

    // Sending synchronous request
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", fileName, false);
        request.overrideMimeType("text/xml");
        request.send(null);

    // Receiving response
    var response = request.responseXML;

    // Changing XML Tree to corresponding XHTML Tree
    response = XMLtoXHTML(response);

    //Adding response to the body
    document.body.appendChild(response);

    // Calling alert
    alert("Hello World");

}
```

**The response gets in fact successfully added to the DOM**, but only after clicking OK on the alert message. When I do a walkthrough using Safari's Script Debugging features, the response *does* get added to the DOM *before* calling alert().

Any suggestions?

NB: I left out other requests.

Comment: Since you're not using an `onreadystatechange` handler, it seems unlikely that the `alert` could ever be called before `appendChild`. Do you have any problems with the multiple AJAX requests not running synchronously, or is this just a test? Could it be that the element is in fact being added, but Safari isn't redrawing the document until after the `alert` is clicked? Have you tried Firefox or IE to see if they do anything different?

Comment: Good call testing it on different platforms. It seems to be a Safari-only problem. I guess you're right asynchronous is just the way to go.

Comment: Really, unless you're specifically trying to prevent user interaction during your requests or you're using a web worker, you should always run your requests async. Synchronous requests are blocking, meaning no other JS on the page can run until the request completes - no JS hover effects, no clicking on buttons, etc - just think if one of those requests is slow or times out... If you just want to chain requests, however, `onreadystatechange` is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it actually does get added, you just don't see the changes before JS returns control back to the browser, i.e. until alert window is closed. If you cannot do an async request (which I would suggest first), you could at least make dom changes in a separate `setTimeout`ed "thread".

Comment: Requesting whatever was in the response after it's been added returns null in Safari, which appears to be not so the case in other browsers.

Answer (score 2):

It has indeed been added to the DOM but the page hasn't parsed the new element into view yet. If I had to guess it would be that since alert blocks the current running JS thread webkit tries to perform reflows during this time for efficiency.

Test case:

```
function foo()
{
   var div = document.createElement("div");
   div.innerHTML = "hi friends";
   div.id = "bar";
   document.body.appendChild(div);
   alert(document.getElementById("bar").innerHTML);
}
```

Do you need the element to appear before the alert comes up? Use this in that case

```
setTimeout(function(){alert("Hello World");}, 1);
```

Comment: Thank you all for the quick replies! ^^ Fine example

Answer (score 0):

Or use a flow control library like [Frame.js](https://github.com/bishopZ/Frame.js) (or asnyc, flow.js, more):

```
Frame(function(next)){ 
    document.body.appendChild(response);
    next();
});
Frame(function(next)){ 
    alert("Hello World");
    next();
});
Frame.init();
```